# Keep My.Settings Always VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, save, my.settings

I have an application and I need to always have the my.settings saved. I notice that they get cleared whenever you change the files location, or run it on a different computer. Are there any ways to prevent this. It also happens when the application updates. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can retain your settings thru an upgrade:

(you also need to define a Project - Properties - Setting settings of 'ApplicationVersion' as string; you can start it off with an initial value of "not yet set")

```
Private Sub SetSettingsVersion()

    Dim a As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    Dim appVersion As Version = a.GetName().Version
    Dim appVersionString As String = appVersion.ToString

    If My.Settings.ApplicationVersion <> appVersion.ToString Then
        My.Settings.Upgrade()
        My.Settings.ApplicationVersion = appVersionString
    End If

End Sub
```